# ASP.NET 5 Web Application that references the new Class Library (package)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package

I am in the process of creating a large solution that contains an ASP.NET 5 MVC Web App which targets the following frameworks:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

I have several of the new Class Library (package) in my solution for the business layer, data layer, etc.. All of these libraries target the following frameworks:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
```

I have a few test projects which target the following frameworks just like my MVC web app does:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": { }
  },
```

After doing much research I mostly found that anything that is a project like my mvc app and test libraries should target dnx and projects that act as class libraries should just keep their defaults and target net/dotnet5.4.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong because from my MVC Web Application I am unable to reference items from my class libraries (DAL, BLL) unless I add dnx451 to them...

Comment: for now you should just change your class library to target dnxcore50 so it matches your web app. later after rc2 there will be new guidance on the target monikers to use so you will want to revisit later

Comment: Ok regardless of the project type you are saying everything should match the webapp defaults which are dnx451 and dnxcore50 correct?

Comment: that will get it working and is fine for now, it is what I'm doing in my own projects but I expect new guidance on it after all the bits stop moving

Comment: When you reference these libraries you add it to the dependencies section that is on the outside and is the dependencies for both dnx451 and dnxcore50 correct? like this: "BusinessLibrary": "1.0.0-*"

Comment: yes your own projects go in the main deps, the ones that were under dotnet5.4 go under dnxcore50

Comment: Ohh!!! so I still need those System. beta references that are under dotnet5.4 when you create a new class library under my dnxcore50 throughout everything? Even the webapps? If you don't mind can you please paste an example of the target frameworks section of your project.json that you are using throughout all of your projects. I will mark it as the correct answer. At this point I am wondering if I simply copy and paste the target frameworks in a new ASP.NET5 mvc app into the class library project.json or if I still need those sub dependencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101788/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-joe-audette).

Comment: In general `dnx451` and `dnxcore50` in *applications* corresponds `net451` and `dotnet5.4` in *class libraries* (see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/98)), but the last changes in the sources of ASP.NET Core uses `dotnet5.6` in class libraries and  `dnxcore50` in applications.

Answer (score 1):

You have  **"dnxcore50"** in your Web application and  **"dotnet5.4"** in your dll, which are probably different sets of referenced libraries. Either your Class Library should target **"dnxcore50"** or your Web App should target **"dotnet5.4"** with all it's dependencies

Comment: So I should try replacing dotnet5.4 with dnxcore50 and keep the net451 in my class libraries? I have already tried making all projects reference dnx451 and dnxcore50 but the class libraries seem to be having issues with the System namespace. You would think that if every single project just targets dnx451 and dnxcore50 I wouldn't have any issues right? Well this new system is so messed up and there are no examples out there using ASP.NET 5 along with Class Libraries so it is very frustrating.

Comment: Same, same but different. The problem is that target frameworks are completely different sets of libraries. if you say that it is dnxcore - it means it will work in dxncore environment and requires dnxcore libraries for that. So all your references should be valid for working in these environments.

Comment: And yes, suppose by eplacing dotnet5.4 with dnxcore50 would make it work

Answer (score 0):

I just kind of resolved similar issue.

Actually, the issue is not the inability to reference your class libraries, but lack of support from Intellisense. You can manually reference your class library in project.json of your application and then use classes from your class library in your application. And application will build and run just fine. At lease mine did build and run. But VS will still highlight your classes form class library with red color and show "Cannot resolve symbol" warning message.

To add support of Intellisense I removed "dnxcore50" from project.json of application and added "net451". So, now I have the following project.json in application:

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dnx451": { }
  },
```

I cannot just reference only "net451" because I can't start the application then. DNX just exits with code 1. But with both "net451" for Intellisense support and "dnx451" for DNX support I'm able to continue work on my project and wait for proper solution in RC2 of ASP.NET Core.